# Understanding servlet path expansion in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, servlets

I have searched high and low for an answer/tutorial on this with no joy. It must be too trivial a question.

I've installed Tomcat 7.0.27 and am messing around with the stock examples. The examples are stored in `webapps/examples` and `server.xml` says the `docBase` is `webapps`. The HTML index of the examples is accessed via `http://localhost:8080/examples/servlets/`. So far, so good.

On this page, hover over the "Execute" link for the "Hello World" servlet and the path expands to: `http://localhost:8080/examples/servlets/servlet/HelloWorldExample`, which executes successfully of course. But `servlet` is supposed to expand to `WEB-INF/classes`. So I would expect the on-disk path to the class to be `webapps/examples/servlets/WEB-INF/classes/HelloWorldExample.class`, which it is not. The actual path is `webapps/examples/WEB-INF/classes/HelloWorldExample.class`. The only thing that's in the `servlets` directory is HTML and image files. Question #1: What's up with that? How did `examples/servlets/servlet` get re-routed to `examples/WEB-INF/classes`?

Question #2: I drop a compiled class `Foo.class` into `WEB-INF/classes` and try to access it both through `http://localhost:8080/examples/servlets/servlet/Foo` and through `http://localhost:8080/examples/servlet/Foo`. Both produce 404 not found. Restarted Tomcat (shouldn't have to, but what the hay) which didn't help. What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't work like that. Servlets != CGI. There is no expansion.

Servlets are specifically mapped in the web.xml to their URL. Their package name, or placement within WEB-INF as a .class, in a .jar, or located some other place on the class path have no bearing on what URL they are mapped to.

Addena, in Servlet 3.0, they can be annotated instead of mapped in web.xml. That doesn't mean necessarily that compiled classes can be "just dropped in". That would be a container feature, I can't say whether Tomcat would allow that or not.

Comment: I appreciate that this [Running a Servlet under Tomcat](http://cs.calstatela.edu/~abbott/Courses/CS_320b/Running%20a%20Servlet%20under%20Tomcat.html) is old. But is it inaccurate?

Comment: I can't speak to its accuracy, I don't know if Tomcat supports that now or not. Tomcat 3 is so very old, it does not surprise me that it once supported such a mechanism, but that was back before the concept of the "Web App" (i.e. the WAR file and its structure and contents) became canon. Today, the web app is the standard deployment mechanism. Even if Tomcat still supported this, I would stay away from it and simply work with the standerd WAR format. Tomcat 3 is 13 years old...